# Spark streaming location filtering

Tags: scala, hadoop, twitter, apache-spark, spark-streaming

My issue about restriction location about which sends twits.I hope you understand my question.

My stream like this.And also i want to take only -for example in Ankara coordinates 30 E 09,,36 N 13.I want to take only this area.How can i do?Also you must not based on like 'E' and 'N' you can say another way for area.

```
val tweets =TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, Array("istanbul")).filter(_.getLang == "tr")
```

Comment: have you any idea for this issue ?